# Principal ideals in Banach lattices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-lattices

Let $E$ be a Banach lattice. Then $u \in E_+$ is said to be a quasi-interior point of $E$ is $$E_u:=\{f \in E:\exists\, c\geq 0 \text{ such that } |f| \leq cu\}$$ is dense in $E.$

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with $C^{\infty}$-boundary and define $u(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega).$ Describe the sets $\left(L^p(\Omega)\right)_{u^2} \, (1\leq p <\infty)$ and $\left(C_0(\Omega)\right)_{u}.$

**My attempt:**

Let $E=L^p(\Omega)$ and $f \in E_{u^2}.$ Then there exists $c\geq 0$ such that $|f| \leq c u^2.$ Therefore $|f|(x) \leq c \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)^2$ for all $x.$ Therefore $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega).$ Therefore $E_{u^2} \subseteq L^{\infty}(\Omega).$ The converse inclusion is obviously true an so $E_{u^2} = L^{\infty}(\Omega).$

For similar reasons, $\left(C_0(\Omega)\right)_{u}=L^{\infty}(\Omega).$

> Am I right?

Comment: "The converse inclusion is obviously true" is false. Any ideal of $C_0$ has to consist of continuous functions

Comment: "The converse inclusion is obviously true" is also false for $L^p$. For instance, the constant function with value $1$ is not contained in $(L^p(\Omega))_{u^2}$

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what kind of description you are looking for. We have $(L^p(\Omega))_{u^2} = \{f \in L^p(\Omega): \; \exists c \ge 0: \, |f| \le cu^2\}$ and $(C_0(\Omega))_u = \{f \in C_0(\Omega): \; \exists c \ge 0: \, |f| \le cu\}$ by the very definition of principal ideals, and I find this already quite explicit ;actually, I don't think we'll get anything more explicit than that if we want to describe these principal ideals as subspaces of $L^p(\Omega)$ and $C_0(\Omega)$. [to be continued]

Comment: [contiuation] However, we can *isometrically isomorphically* describe these principal ideals of we endow them with the gauge norm: the space $(L^p(\Omega))_{u^2}$ is isometrically lattice isomorphic (but not equal) to $L^\infty(\Omega)$, and the space $(C_0(\Omega))_u$ is isometrically lattice isomorphic (but of course not equal) to $C_b(\Omega)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Lattice isomorphic seems nice enough. I was mainly trying to figure out how to show an element is in the principal ideal, so I thought it would be nice to consider examples. Say, for example, I already know $f \in C^{k}(\overline{\Omega})$ for sufficiently large $k,$ and I want to show $f \in \left(L^p(\Omega)\right)_{u^2}.$ Is it sufficient to show $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @Mark: Well, lattice isomorphic is indeed nice, but not the right notion if you want to check that a concrete function is contained in a principal ideal. If you have a certain function $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ and want to prove that $f \in (L^p(\Omega))_{u^2}$, then I think there's no other way then just proving that there exists a constant $c \ge 0$ such that $|f| \le c u^2$. "Bounded and smooth" is of course not enough since the constant function with value $1$ is bounded and smooth, but not in $(L^p(\Omega))_{u^2}$. [to be continued.]

Comment: [continuation] But smoothness up to the boundary can help you to prove that $|f| \le cu^2$ for some number $c \ge 0$: If $f \in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ and $f$ vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$ and the normal derivative of $f$ vanishes on the boundary, too, then $|f|$ can indeed by dominated by a multiple of $u^2$ (this is mainly the definition of the derivative - I think the best way to get an intuition for this is to first consider the one-dimensional case $\Omega = (0,1)$).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Hmm, so if $f \in C^2(\overline{\Omega}),$ then $f$ is bounded and $|f|$ would be dominated by a multiple of $u^2$ if $f=0,$ whenever $u=0?$ Why do we also need the normal derivative of $f$ to vanish on the boundary?

Comment: @Mark: I think it is really helpful to consider the one-dimensional case - say on the interval $\Omega = (-1,1)$: then $u(x) = 1-|x|$ for all $x \in \Omega$. Now consider, say, the function $f$ given by $f(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ for $x \in \Omega$. Then $f$ vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$, but the (normal) derivative of $f$ does not vanish there. If you draw a sketch of $f$ and $u^2$, you can easily see that $f (=|f|)$ is not dominated by multiple of $u^2$ since $u^2$ vanishes "quadratically" at $-1$ and $1$, while $f$ vanishes only "linearly".

Comment: @JochenGlueck I see. I tried to see other examples too in the one-dimension case and it does seem that when $f$ and $f'$ vanish on the boundary, then $|f|$ is dominated a multiple of $u^2.$ But I don't see algebraically the role of the derivative here. How would one prove this rigorously?

Comment: @Mark: Taylor approximation of order $2$ implies that $f$ is dominated by $u$ close to the boundary of $\Omega$; and in a compact subset of $\Omega$, there is no problem since $u$ is bounded away from $0$ there.